# Why does attempting to make a design-time connection between my Layout file and its Activity fail in this case?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-linearlayout, design-time

Based on what I discerned on hooking up Layouts to Activities at design time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744235/how-can-i-get-my-layout-file-to-show-its-label-as-others-do), I added this to one of my Layout files:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="hhs.app.SettingsActivity
```

...and yet it does not work (I want the label for the Activity to display in the Action Bar), as another Layout/Activity pair does. Why not?

In context, the XML is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="hhs.app.SettingsActivity"
     >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email:"
        android:padding="5dip"
        />
    <EditText
        . . .
</LinearLayout>
```

The expected label for the Activity *does* display in the Action Bar at run/emulate-time, so the code in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name="hhs.app.SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
</activity>
```

...and strings.xml:

```
<string name="title_activity_settings">HHS Settings</string>
```

...is hooking up fine (again, at run/emulate-time, but not at design time). Why the declarative mismatch/selective blindness on the part of the design-time Layout engine?

Comment: The design tools in Eclipse suck.  They don't do any more than the minimum, and they get that wrong.  They're only useful for very small, simple layouts.  Anything else do in pure xml or you'll go insane (and not get the results you're expecting).

Comment: Eclipse designer is awful.  Switch to Android Studio and you'll never regret it.  Eclipse designer was maybe 75% accurate for me, AS designer is about 95% accurate (probably not 100% because it's still in early access stage).

Comment: This is Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this issue is tracked in
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69841
so I'll follow up there.